# Pass the same randomly generated list to both POST and GET views in python/django

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a quiz app which pulls a random subset of 3 questions the queryset Trivia.  I can generate the random subset without issue and display 3 multiple choice questions.  But when the user makes selections and submits, the trivia view generates a new random subset.  Thus, user answers are then compared to correct answers of a new random subset rather than the initial subset that the user viewed.  How can I create this random subset and use it in both the GET and POST methods of my view?  That is, I want the queryset "trivia" to be identical in both GET and POST methods.  Ideas?

def trivia(request):

```
trivia_id_list = Trivia.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
random_trivia_id_list = random.sample(list(trivia_id_list), min(len(trivia_id_list),3))
trivia = Trivia.objects.filter(id__in=random_trivia_id_list)

if request.method == 'POST':
    correct = 0
    incorrect = 0
    total = 0

    for t in trivia:
        print(request.POST.get(t.question))
        print(t.answer)
        print()
        if t.answer == request.POST.get(t.question):
            correct = correct + 1
        else:
            incorrect = incorrect + 1
        total = total + 1
    result = correct/total
    return render(request, 'ColdBlooded/result.html', {
        "Incorrect": incorrect,
        "Correct": correct,
        "Total": total,
        "Trivia": trivia,
        "Result": result,
    })
else:
    return render(request, "ColdBlooded/trivia.html", {
        "Trivia": trivia
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the first three lines

```
trivia_id_list = Trivia.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)
random_trivia_id_list = random.sample(list(trivia_id_list), min(len(trivia_id_list),3))
trivia = Trivia.objects.filter(id__in=random_trivia_id_list)
```

Every time you visit the page, the above code block is executed. For example, if the user visits the page(GET) request, the above code block will return three random questions. If the user tried to answer the questions(POST) request, the above code block will be called again and generate different question than the one in the GET request.

Simple solution:
Put the first three lines in a function and call them only in the GET request(else condition), and in case of POST compare the results with the one in POST. Make sure to define a list that contain the questions called in the GET and clear it every time POST is called.

Note:

Define the list that contains the three questions as a global variable so it does not get initialized every time.